I set up a Flask Server to run jobs on a standalone spark cluster. Spark cluster was not affected, but Flask server keeps crashing
Attempted setting up Flask app to serve requests to a Standalone local spark cluster.
Running the 3 Worker node cluster on an 8GB windows VM in Azure (for testing)
On the same VM I was also running my flask server, exposing the 5000 port to my laptop's IP to accept requests. It was running fine even with multiple concurrent requests from Postman until I started load testing it with my typical daily ETL Pipelines sending through HTTP Requests, The Flask Server would crash. It was a low memory VM so I figured that's what the issue was.
Then I tried setting up the Flask Server on my local system and connecting to the Master node IP. My Flask Server was connecting to the master node, but the Spark cluster was affected by this and kept killing worker nodes and restarting them. This meant that any job I would submit to spark master through my Flask server would just queue forever.
Has anyone done this before successfully? I have since moved on from this approach but wanted some clarity on what went wrong here. I am aware that Livy exists, but the documentation and examples seemed sparse.
